What does it mean, when someone answers a question like "何円を持ってますか？" with "何円です"?
I looked it up in a couple places, and found 何十万円台の収入 in one of the example sentences, which got me curious. I remember reading in a couple places about it, but could never find anything about using 何+a counter being used as a statement, instead of as a way to ask about something

The mental model I use is that Japanese doesn't actually use questions in the same sense that Western languages do. Instead, it follows the Chinese model. In 何円を持ってますか, the か isn't turning a statement into a question, but instead just serving as a marker of doubt or uncertainty. The 何 isn't a question word like "what", but instead a blank to be filled in. The combination of 何 with a counter, then, stands for an unknown quantity.
With this understanding, many mysteries immediately unravel themselves:

Japanese doesn't need any special grammar rules for questions, like how English inverts word order (statement "There is an X" -> question "Is there an X?") - because the "blank" words like 何, どこ, どの etc. are grammatically just nouns.

Similarly, Japanese doesn't need to make a grammatical distinction between direct and indirect questions (English direct question "Is there an X?" -> indirect question "I wondered whether there was an X" restores the declarative word order) - because there's no point.

Sentence-enders can use か like in かも（知らない）, because it doesn't turn the statement into a question but simply expresses doubt.

And finally: as in your question, since 何 is just a placeholder, it can also be used declaratively. Logically, in the place where a number or digit would be expected, it just means some unknown number or digit:


何円 -> some (number of) yen
何十万円 -> (some number of) hundreds of thousands of yen
This is reinforced here by 台 (see meaning 5). The entire phrase describes what might colloquially be translated as "a six-digit income". (Of course, for a variety of reasons, the cultural significance of the phrase is very different.)

I don't understand the objection to the answer.

「何円持っていますか。」（普通は「いくら持っていますか」と言うでしょうけど。）は、質問ですね。「何円か持っています。」と勘違いされました？

I didn't get confused, but I didn't consider the effect of the position of か either. Regardless, I'm still convinced that the understanding of what a "question" is, is culturally/linguistically mediated. (Though some have greatly overstated the conclusions, I do generally lean in favour of the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis.) I'll make a note to come back later if I can think of a way to improve this.
